# Flex-wrap: Same space between rows?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

After a long time, I now have the possibility to work again with the css property `flex`.
The `justify-content: space-between;` works great, but now I'd like to have space between the rows too (which should be the same space as it is between the single boxes in a row – see image attached).

Is there any possibility to do this easily?

[image]

Comment: You can add `margin-bottom` on flex items.

Comment: But the space between is calculated automatically from CSS. How could I set the margin that it is always the same value?

Comment: Have you assigned width to flex items?

Comment: Yes, they have a width of 325px.

Comment: If you want the "same space", I don't think you can do that easily: you would have to calculate the space once the DOM is stable, and then apply it (as margin-bottom). And of course recalculate the space if the viewport size changes (user redimensioning browser's window), and apply it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can achieve it with pure css. The easiest js would be something like this:

Click in *Full page* below the Code Snippet or [test it in Codepen](http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/VmbdNd)

```js
function vertSpace() {
  var container = $("section"),
      containerWidth = container.outerWidth(),
      elem = container.find(".box"),
      elemWidth = elem.first().outerWidth(),
      num = Math.floor(containerWidth / elemWidth),
      space = (containerWidth - num*elemWidth) / (num - 1);
  elem.css("margin-bottom",space +"px") 
}

$(window).on("load resize",function(e){
  vertSpace();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
}
section .box {
  background-color: silver;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 20em;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 20em;
          flex: 0 0 20em;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
  <div class="box">
    elem 1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    elem 2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    elem 3
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    elem 4
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    elem 5
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    elem 6
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    elem 7
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    elem 8
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    elem 9
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot!